# Can't create a .exe with python kivy on windows (Pyinstaller)

Tags: python, kivy, packaging

So, I'm trying to make a .exe from a python kivy code, The .exe is made, but it doesn't open. No message, nothing. I'm checking the logs but theres no problem in there, so I'm completely in the dark here. I'm using the following .spec

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer
spec_root = os.path.abspath(SPECPATH)
app_name = 'Gameficacao'

a = Analysis(['C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/Gameficacao.py'],
             pathex=[spec_root],
             datas=[('C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/*.kv', '.'), ('C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/img/*.png', './img'),('C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/font/*.ttf', './font'),('C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/som/*.mp3', './som')],
             hiddenimports=['win32timezone'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name=app_name,
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=False)
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p)
for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins +  gstreamer.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               name=app_name)
```

If you guys have anything that can help me (ANYTHING), please let me know.

Comment: Consider programming in some different programming language, perhaps [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf); with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could obtain an executable from C++ code. Otherwise, read documentation of  [Python](http://python.org/)

Comment: That's not an option, unfortunattely. The python code is ready and it took a while to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.
FIRST OF ALL, if you are having this problem, you will have to first add the following line to your code:

```
def reset():
    import kivy.core.window as window
    from kivy.base import EventLoop
    if not EventLoop.event_listeners:
        from kivy.cache import Cache
        window.Window = window.core_select_lib('window', window.window_impl, True)
        Cache.print_usage()
        for cat in Cache._categories:
            Cache._objects[cat] = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reset()
    'your app name here'().run()
```

That will prevent the app from not opening (like when it looks like its loading but nothing opens).
AFTER THAT, you wanna build using the spec like this:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Artur\\PycharmProjects\\gameficacao\\Gameficacao.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Artur\\Desktop\\Trabalho\\Gameficacao'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/*.kv', '.'), ('C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/img/*.png', './img'),('C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/font/*.ttf', './font'),('C:/Users/Artur/PycharmProjects/gameficacao/som/*.mp3', './som')],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn','win32timezone','six','packaging','packaging.version','webbrowser','kivy','enchant'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Gameficacao',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins +  gstreamer.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Gameficacao')
```

Now, some things are VERY IMPORTANT here and the app probably won't run without it, and those are:

1. The line **"from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer"**, right on the top
2. **The filling of the data part of the Analysis**, here you will have to indicate the path of every file you will use on your app, including the kivy file. Use mine as a example.
3. The **hiddenimports** line, here you will point out every import that is relevant for your app and that PyInstaller is not able to do. For starters, you will probably want to put the **'pkg_resources.py2_warn'**, since PyInstaller can't import it properly and you will need it.
4. The line **"*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins +  gstreamer.dep_bins)],"** will be a complement from the imports done on the beggining of the code.

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your .py file to .exe you can use [cx_freeze](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/) module. To install it open your cmd and type `pip install cx_freeze` once it is installed make a new .py file and add the below code.

```
        from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
        setup(name = "<anyname>",
              version = "<any version>",
              description = "<add description you want>",
              executables = [Executable(r"<give the path where your python file is  
              located> ")]
              )
```

save this file as setup.py or any name you want to save it and keep this file in the same folder.
Then in that folder open the "open command window here" you can do this by pressing the shift key and right-click simultaneously.
Then in the command type `python setup.py(or the name you have given to new file) build`.
It will create a build folder and in that folder, you will find your .exe file.

Comment: How does that work with kivy ? I'm using pyinstaller because thats what the kivy guide recommended. Do I need to do anything differently because of kivy?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Do you have some additional file like .kv or some other files

Answer (score 1):

if it is the same problem as my, refers to ours old openGL, 1.1 in my case, and I can't upgrade cause my graphic card is also old. So you cant put this line on your main code:

```
      from kivy_deps import angle
      import os

      os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] ='angle_sdl2'
```

After this, you need to import in the .spec file:

```
    from kivy_deps import angle,sdl2, glew


    coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('folder of your .kv 
    file'),
        a.binaries,
        a.zipfiles,
        a.datas,
        *[Tree(p) for p in(angle.dep_bins + 
        sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
        strip=False,
        upx=True,
        upx_exclude=[],
        name='name')
```

To create the exe. make sure you have the UPX, if you don't, download and put it in the same directory you are runing the pyinstaller.